# difference between two dates in java in 'EST' time zone

Tags: java, date, calendar

I have to parse a string to a date, let us say `givenDate`, to EST timezone.
Also, I have to take the current date, let us say `currentDate` in EST timezone.
My current timezone is IST (GMT+5:30).

If the currentDate is greater than givenDate then I need to add a day to currentDate.

Here is the solution that I have implemented.

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Calendar givenDate = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
givenDate .setTime(df.parse("01/08/2016"));

Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
if(currentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR) > givenDate .get(Calendar.YEAR) ||
            currentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) > givenDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)){
        currentDate.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
}

System.out.println("Final date : "+df.format(currentDate.getTime()));
```

> Is there any better solution for this?

Also, the following has been tickling my mind.

Consider code snippet

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");   
Calendar givenDate = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
givenDate .setTime(df.parse("01/07/2016"));
System.out.println(givenDate .get(Calendar.DATE));         //6       
System.out.println(givenDate .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)); //6
System.out.println(givenDate .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));  //6
```

> Why am I getting 6 for DATE, DAY_OF_MONTH, DAY_OF_YEAR? I would expect
>   they must return 7 as the given date is 7 days from the starting of
>   the year 2016.

But if I add the following line after first line of above code, above mentioned fields are returning 7. What could be the reason of this?

```
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
```

.

Comment: Please update your post with concrete examples covering all the possible cases, showing inputs and expected outputs.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the timezone into the SimpleDateFormat class, and then you can compare the parsed Date with the current time:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
Date givenDate = df.parse("01/08/2016");

Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();

if(currentDate.getTime().compareTo(givenDate) > 0) {
    currentTime.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
}
```

Keep in mind that a Date object represents the current time (number of seconds since epoch) in UTC timezone.

Comment: But I need current date in EST time zone.

Comment: The Date object always represents the time in UTC regardless of how you got it. Even givenDate in your example is in UTC. The timezone only takes effect when you parse from a specific date/time, or when you format a date/time. And current time (from a new Date or Calendar object) is always correct regardless of your timezone.